# How does chroot-escape protection in LXC implemented

Tags: security, chroot, lxc

How does chroot-escape protection in LXC implemented? Is there guarantee, that there no way to escape from lxc container to host?

I know, that linux-vserver uses chroot-barrier for that, but it doesn't part of stock kernel, afair.

Answer (score 2):

Did you see the info contained in the "Applying mount namespaces" article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-mount-namespaces/

Under the "Per-user root" section:

"One shortcoming of this approach is that an ordinary chroot() can be escaped, although some privilege is needed. For instance, when executed with certain capabilities including CAP_SYS_CHROOT, the source for a program to break out of chroot() (see Resources) will cause the program to escape into the real filesystem root. Depending on the actual motivation for and use of the per-user filesystem trees, this may be a problem.

We can address this problem by using pivot_root(2) in a private namespace instead of chroot(2) to change the login's root to /share/USER/root. Whereas chroot() simply points the process's filesystem root to a specified new directory, pivot_root() detaches the specified new_root directory (which must be a mount) from its mount point and attaches it to the process root directory. Since the mount tree has no parent for the new root, the system cannot be tricked into entering it like it can with chroot(). We will use the pivot_root() approach."

In short I've seen pivot_root used in combination with the mnt namespace to mitigate such concerns.

Comment: but pivot_root can't be used for any directory -- only for mountpoint. and --bind is not mountpoint... or it is?

Comment: @datacompboy, quite some time ago, but just stumbled on this with the same question in mind. Linux source code says bind mount is ok for pivot_root:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/namespace.c#L3061